# Will two convex hulls overlap?

Tags: geometry, probability-theory

I ran into the following problem while working in neural nets.

Given natural numbers $b$ and $r$, uniformly randomly choose $b+r$ points within a unit square. Call the $b$ points the *blue points* and the $r$ points  *red points*. What is the probability $p(b,r)$ that the convex hull of the blue points, $H_b$ , overlaps with $H_r$?

**Partial answer**  : I can't immediately think of anything but a multi-fold brute-force integral for this. Intuitively, it seems to me (I could be incorrect) that $p(b,r)$ has to satisfy $\lim_{b\rightarrow \infty} p(b,r)   = 1$ and likewise $p(b,r) \rightarrow 0$ as $b$ or $r$ approach 0. Also, given $b$ random points, we can compute the expected size of its convex hull according to  [this paper](http://biomet.oxfordjournals.org/content/52/3-4/331.full.pdf) , though it's not clear to me how to use this.

I don't know how to connect  these disparate hints at solution and would like suggestions.

Comment: Let $n=b+r$, so you choose $n$ points. How do you know which of these points are "the $b$ points", and which are "the $r$ points"?